# callback jquery function not working correct

Tags: jquery

I want that screenCheck function show run only after Validation of `#contact_email`. But in my case its running before that. how do I correct it?

```
<script>
function screenCheck() {
    var screenWidth = window.screen.width;
    if (screenWidth == '1024') {
        $('#textAreaMsg label.error').css('margin-left', '99px');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_email").validate(screenCkeck());​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [JQuery validator plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), you need to pass the callback as part of the options map.  For example, to make your callback run after the form has been deemed invalid, you'd write it like this:

```
$("#contact_email").validate({
    invalidHandler: screenCheck
});
```

The same goes for the *submitHandler* and/or the *showErrors* handler.  To handle all three, you'd write it like this:

```
$("#contact_email").validate({
    invalidHandler: screenCheck,
    submitHandler: submitCallback,
    showErrors: showErrorsCallback
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try to pass you callback without `()`

```
$("#contact_email").validate(screenCheck);
```

Please also note that your function is called `screenCheck` and not `screenCkeck`

Comment: did you `Check/Ckeck` the function name ? If it's still not working please specify which plugin you're using (so I can see the code)

Answer (score 1):

Beside @F. Calderan mentionded, I think  your

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#contact_email").validate(screenCkeck());​
```

need a closing `)};` like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#contact_email").validate(screenCheck);​
}); // need closing
```